# How to set up config in NestJS properly?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, nestjs-config

I'm using `nest-modules/mailer` to send an email and I have some trouble during the config setup for `MailerModule`.

(1) Previously I was using a raw `dotenv` package to my config in `main.ts` like:

```typescript
dotenv.config({
  path: 'src/config/config.env',
});
```

But I can't assign the config to `MailerModule` in `app.module.ts`.

(2) Then I tried to setup config using `@nesjs/config` and the `app.module.ts` looks like this:

```typescript
import config from 'src/config/config';

@Module({
  controllers: [
    //...
  ],
  providers: [
   //...
 ],
  imports: [
    HttpModule,
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      load: [config]
    }),
    MailerModule.forRoot({
      transport: {
        ignoreTLS: true,
        secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
        host: process.env.EMAIL_HOST,
        port: process.env.EMAIL_PORT,
        auth: {
          user: process.env.EMAILDEV_INCOMING_USER,
          pass: process.env.EMAILDEV_INCOMING_PWD 
        },
      },
      defaults: {
        from: `'nest-modules' ${process.env.EMAILDEV_INCOMING_}`, // outgoing email ID
      },
      template: {
     
      },
    })
  ]
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
 //...
}
```

So there's no way I can use `configService`  and `process.env.*` to load the config for `MailerModule`.

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to solve this properly at the current stage:

load the `EmailModule` asynchronously (and others you need to use configs).

```
imports: [
    HttpModule,
    MailerModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: async () => {
        return {
          transport: {
            ignoreTLS: true,
            secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
            host: process.env.EMAIL_HOST,
            port: process.env.EMAIL_PORT,
            auth: {
              user: process.env.EMAILDEV_INCOMING_USER, // generated ethereal user
              pass: process.env.EMAILDEV_INCOMING_PWD // generated ethereal password
            },
          },
          defaults: {
            from: `'nest-modules' ${process.env.EMAILDEV_INCOMING_}`, // outgoing email ID
          },
          template: {
            dir: process.cwd() + '/src/shared/static/views',
            adapter: new HandlebarsAdapter(),
            options: {
              strict: true,
            },
          },
        }
      }
    })
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [sample](https://github.com/nest-modules/mailer/blob/master/sample/01-basic/src/app.module.ts) code provided with `nest-modules/mailer` it is enough to load your `.env` like this in `AppModule`, directly from dotenv with a `require` import:

```
require('dotenv').config({
  path: 'src/config/config.env',
});
```

And you can probably also use a typescript import of dotenv and call `config()` in a line above your `AppModule` definition or, better, in your main.ts `bootstrap()` function before you instantiate the NestJS app.

Answer (score 0):

Import configService in the app.module.ts and then you can use it in the MailerModule:

```
 @Module({
  imports: [
    MailerModule.forRootAsync({
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        transport: {
          host: configService.get('MAILHOG_HOST'),
          port: Number(configService.get('MAILHOG_SMTP_PORT')),
          secure: false,
        },
        defaults: {
          from: 'Hello @Company <hello@company.com>',
        },
        template: {
          dir: join(__dirname, 'templates'),
          adapter: new EjsAdapter(),
          options: {
            strict: true,
          },
        },
      }),
    }),
  ],
  providers: [EmailService],
})
```